# Jaeger space between spans

Tags: spring-boot, opentracing, jaeger

I'm using jaeger with spring boot to trace a test application, sometimes I get some extra space or overlap that appears between spans in a single-threaded trace that takes up to 20ms.
I am confused about this extra space because there aren't any codes between these spans and I expected to see spans starting after each other.
Here are my output results.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is why tracing is a useful tool, it often reveals issues like this that you wouldn't suspect otherwise. If your application is using async framework, these gaps may indicate execution waiting on available threads. Or your application may be CPU throttled during and between the spans. You cannot really explain the gaps from the trace itself, but you surely do have them. Time to whip out the profiler.